Booking flight from Nairobi to Bahamas with 1 layover in Germany
I want to travel to Bahamas from Nairobi Kenya. But I want to have a layover in Germany esp Frankfurt or Munich airports. Can it be possible? Do airlines allow passengers to choose layovers?

Well, they do if the airline offers the route.

Welcome to Travel.SE. We expect participants here to attempt to answer their own questions, and let us know what they have discovered and what they still need help with. I'll suggest you might begin by searching Google Flights which will show what flight segments are available for purchase. You can specify layover airports too.

Tricky.
Nairobi to Frankfurt is served daily by Lufthansa but Lufthansa doesn't serve Nassau so they would have to use a code share (probably with United) which they currently don't offer.

Do airlines allow passengers to choose layovers?

Yes and no. First: we need to distinguish between a layover and a stopover. A layover is a connection at an airport where there is no intend to leave the airport (although sometimes you can). In most cases you can stay in the international transit area (other than the US and Canada, that is) and you often don't need a Visa etc for the layover country (again, there are exceptions). In case of delay or cancellation the airline can change a layover without your permission. It's not a guaranteed stop.
A stopover on the other hand means that you want to enter the stopover country for some amount of time. Your bags will be unloaded and you need full documentation to enter the country. A stopover can be just a few hours but also days. months, or weeks. The stop is guaranteed and you cannot be rerouted.
The way to book a stopover is to book this as a multi city trip where you can directly specify FRA or MUC as a stop and you can also specify how long you would like to stay there.
Unfortunately, almost all connection between Europe and The Bahamas will route through the US or Canada, typically with a long layover. That also means that you would need full entry credentials for the US or Canada.
Here is example of such a trip


BA has flights LHR-NAS, which would be a very reasonable connection option from Europe, with less onerous visa requirements.

@NateEldredge: yes. but that's the only one and it requires to fly with One World which will makes routing to FRA or MUC tricky (since they are Star Alliance hubs).

Thanks, @Damila. Brain fade on my part. I'll delete, correct, and re-post my comment.

It's also worth noting that as a (presumably) Kenyan citizen, the OP may need a visa to transit in the UK (at Heathrow, for instance) even if the transit is only a few hours and they plan to remain within the airport while waiting for the flight to the Bahamas. See this UK government website for more on this specific issue.

(It's worth noting that they'd also need a visa to transit in Germany especially with a stopover)
